# Struts 2 validation not working properly as application grows

Tags: java, validation, struts2, annotations, struts

Is there any alternative validation framework while building complex web app? Or any guide for validation. Links to example is not required as it working on simple Form but not in complex Form with multiple links.

This is my action class

```
package com.tpc.action;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
 import com.tpc.domain.LeadFacultyModel;
 import com.tpc.service.LeadFacultyServiceInterface;

  public class LeadFacultyAction extends ActionSupport {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


private LeadFacultyModel leadFacultyModel;

private String lead_faculty_formAction;

// Injecting leadFacultyServiceImpl bean 
LeadFacultyServiceInterface leadFacultyServiceImpl;


//variable to store the action message to pass to other pages through get request
private String action_msg = null;

private List<LeadFacultyModel> leadFacultyModelList = new ArrayList<LeadFacultyModel>();


public String execute() throws Exception {
    return SUCCESS;
}


public String formAction() throws Exception
{
    if(lead_faculty_formAction.equals("Save"))
    {
        System.out.println("Inside Update");
        return this.updateLeadFaculty();
    }
    else if(lead_faculty_formAction.equals("Submit"))
    {
        System.out.println("Inside Save");
        return this.saveLeadFaculty();      
    }
    else if(lead_faculty_formAction.equals("Delete"))
    {
        System.out.println("Inside Delete");
        return this.deleteLeadFaculty();
    }
    else
    {
        return SUCCESS;
    }           

}

public String saveLeadFaculty() throws Exception {

    boolean result =leadFacultyServiceImpl.createLeadFaculty(leadFacultyModel);
    if(result == true)
    {
        addActionMessage(getText("message.save_success"));
        return "SAVE_SUCCESS";
    }
    else {
        addActionError(getText("message.save_error"));
        return  "SAVE_ERROR";
    }

}

public String viewAllLeadFaculty(){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("view all method is called");
    try{
        leadFacultyModelList = leadFacultyServiceImpl.getAllLeadFaculty();
        System.out.println("Action page "+leadFacultyModelList.size());
        return SUCCESS;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return ERROR;
    }


}



//Section of getter/setter methods in this class

public void setLeadFacultyModel(LeadFacultyModel leadFacultyModel) {
    this.leadFacultyModel = leadFacultyModel;
}

public LeadFacultyModel getLeadFacultyModel() {
    return leadFacultyModel;
}

public String getLead_faculty_formAction() {
    return lead_faculty_formAction;
}
public void setLead_faculty_formAction(String lead_faculty_formAction) {
    this.lead_faculty_formAction = lead_faculty_formAction;
}

public void setLeadFacultyServiceImpl(
        LeadFacultyServiceInterface leadFacultyServiceImpl) {
    this.leadFacultyServiceImpl = leadFacultyServiceImpl;
}

public void setAction_msg(String action_msg) {
    this.action_msg = action_msg;
}

public List<LeadFacultyModel> getLeadFacultyModelList() {
    return leadFacultyModelList;
}

public void setLeadFacultyModelList(List<LeadFacultyModel> leadFacultyModelList) {
    this.leadFacultyModelList = leadFacultyModelList;
}

public String getAction_msg() {
    return action_msg;
}   
}
```

This is LeadFacultyAction-validation.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">



<validators>
    <field name="leadFacultyModel.lead_string_FacultyName">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
     <message>Name is required.</message>
    </field-validator>
    </field>
  </validators>
```

this is struts.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">

<!-- /** defining result types for implementing tiles **/ -->
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles"
            class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
    </result-types>
    <global-results>
        <result name="error">/404_error.jsp</result>
    </global-results>
    <action name="">
        <result></result>
    </action>
    <action name="baseTemplate" >
        <result type="tiles">baseTemplate</result>
    </action>


    <action name="setup_lead_faculty">
        <result type="tiles">setup_lead_faculty</result>
    </action>

    <action name="setup_LeadFacultyAction" class="com.tpc.action.LeadFacultyAction" method="formAction">
        <result name="SAVE_SUCCESS" type="tiles">setup_lead_faculty</result>
        <result name="UPDATE_SUCCESS" type="tiles">setup_lead_faculty</result>
        <result name="DELETE_SUCCESS" type="tiles">setup_lead_faculty</result>
        <result name="SAVE_ERROR" type="tiles">setup_lead_faculty</result>
        <result name="UPDATE_ERROR" type="tiles">setup_lead_faculty</result>
        <result name="DELETE_ERROR" type="tiles">setup_lead_faculty</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">setup_lead_faculty</result>
    </action>

    <action name="setup_LeadFaculty_list_view_Action" class="com.tpc.action.LeadFacultyAction" method="viewAllLeadFaculty">
        <result type="tiles" name="success">setup_lead_faculty_list_view</result>
    </action>

    <action name="setup_LeadFacultyAction_selected_from_list" class="com.tpc.action.LeadFacultyAction" method="getByIdLeadFaculty">
        <result type="tiles" name="success">setup_lead_faculty</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

This is my JSP file:

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
 <c:set value="/lms/" var="baseUrl" />
<s:form method="post" action="setup_LeadFacultyAction">
<div class="buttontab">
    <input type="submit" name="lead_faculty_formAction" value="Save"
        class="form_button" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="submit"
        name="lead_faculty_formAction" value="Submit" class="form_button" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="submit" name="lead_faculty_formAction"
        value="Delete" class="form_button" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input
        type="submit" name="lead_faculty_formAction" value="Reset"     disabled="disabled"
        class="form_button" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="span"
        style="float: right;"> <i><a   href="${baseUrl}lead/setup_LeadFaculty_list_view_Action"> <img
            src="${baseUrl}icons/gridview.png" width="12px" height="12px" /></a> </i> </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span class="span" style="float: right;"> <i><img
            src="${baseUrl}icons/formview.png" width="12px" height="12px" /> </i> </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span class="span" style="float: right;"> <i><img
            src="${baseUrl}icons/tileview.png" width="12px" height="12px" /> </i> </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
<div id="content_wrap">
    <div class="unidiv1">

        <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
            <div class="errors">
                <s:actionerror/>
            </div>
        </s:if>
        <s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
            <div>
                <p><s:actionmessage/></p>
            </div>      
        </s:if>
        <s:if test="hasFieldErrors()">
            <div>
                <p><s:fielderror/></p>
            </div>      
        </s:if>

        <div class="field_wrapper">
            <div class="left_box">
                <label>ID</label>
            </div>
            <div class="right_box">
                <input type="text" name="leadFacultyModel.lead_string_FacultyId" value="${leadFacultyModel.lead_string_FacultyId}"
                    class="input_id" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field_wrapper">
            <div class="left_box">
                <label>Faculy</label>
            </div>
            <div class="right_box">
                <input type="text" name="leadFacultyModel.lead_string_FacultyName" value="${leadFacultyModel.lead_string_FacultyName }" />
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="field_wrapper">
            <div class="left_box">
                <label>Remarks</label>
            </div>
            <div class="right_box">
                <textarea name="leadFacultyModel.lead_string_FacultyRemarks"
                    class="textarea_address">${leadFacultyModel.lead_string_FacultyRemarks}</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Struts2 validation? Show what is not working.

Comment: Define "not working properly".

Comment: If you want to avoid answers like "No and Yes", ask a more concrete question. If you show the JSP and the Action code you use, people will also be able to find the bug that is causing problems for you, and that you think stem from the framework.

Comment: ok i will do that but i cannot post the code i am working now so i will build another version and post it thanks for ur replies

Comment: My problem is that validation works fine, but when i click           '<a href="${baseUrl}lead/setup_LeadFaculty_list_view_Action">' but it does not load list although it calls setup_LeadFaculty_list_view_Action action from struts.xml and when i remove the validation list is populated again

Comment: You define validation for the entire action, not separate methods; the validation will fire regardless of which action method you call.

Comment: so whats the solution for this I need to trigger an action to populate the list on another page if user tends to view the list instead of filling form

Comment: @Dipen If you want to turn off validation on some method you could use `@SkipVlidation` annotation.

Comment: thanks for your response now i have some idea and your suggestion helped me a lot but i have seen some annotation based validation i.e. Using Bean Validation, struts2 annotation based validation but is the working mechanism of annotation based validation different from xml declared validation. For now i have removed struts2 validation done validation manually in code

Comment: @AleksandrM now i have posted my code please suggest me something and thanks in advance

Comment: @Akku now i have posted my code please suggest me something and thanks in advance

Comment: @RomanC thanks a lot it worked but if you time please post some example of annotation based validation and whats difference between annotation based and xml based validation lastly thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is only if Struts discover validation annotations while intercepting the action it processes those annotations to perform validations by applying validation rules exposed by annotations. The same thing is when parsing `-validation.xml`. You can use both validation methods xml based and annotation based together, or with addition to custom validation (excluding custom validators).

For example, if I have a `phone` field and I want to validate it is not empty and contains a predefined format I will just put two annotations on it.

```
  private String phone;

  public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
  }

  @RequiredStringValidator(type= ValidatorType.FIELD, message="Phone required.")
  @RegexFieldValidator(type= ValidatorType.FIELD, message="Invalid Phone",
    regexExpression="\\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\\)\\s[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")
  public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
  }
```

then I have an `execute` action I *don't want* to validate

```
  @SkipValidation
  public String execute() throws Exception {
```

then I have another action `save` that I want to validate `questions` but I don't want to validate a `phone`.

```
  private String myQuestionq1;
  private String myQuestionq2;

  public String getMyQuestionq1() {
    return myQuestionq1;
  }

  public void setMyQuestionq1(String myQuestionq1) {
    this.myQuestionq1 = myQuestionq1;
  }

  public String getMyQuestionq2() {
    return myQuestionq2;
  }

  public void setMyQuestionq2(String myQuestionq2) {
    this.myQuestionq2 = myQuestionq2;
  }

  @Action(value="save", results = {
    @Result(name="input", location = "/default.jsp"),
    @Result(name="back", type="redirect", location = "/")

  },interceptorRefs = @InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params = {"validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"}))
  @Validations(requiredFields = {
      @RequiredFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.FIELD, fieldName = "myQuestionq1", message = "You must enter a value for field myQuestionq1."),
      @RequiredFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.FIELD, fieldName = "myQuestionq2", message = "You must enter a value for field myQuestionq2.")
  })
  public String save() throws SQLException {
```

this will execute only validators on this action.

More examples you could always find on Apache web site:
[Validation using annotations examples.](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-annotation)