# struts.xml redirect action with 'file' param?

Tags: java, xml, redirect, struts2

Assume I have an action to validate a form. If this method returns success, it is being redirected to a new action with all its parameters. One of my parameters is of type:

> java.io.File

And this causes the redirected action to return INPUT instead of SUCCESS.

Here's my code:

```
   public String validateMemberForm() {
    int fails = 0;
    if (service.findMemberByCompany(company) != null) {
        addFieldError("company", "This company is already registered!");
        fails++;
    }
    if (service.findMemberByEmail(email) != null) {
        addFieldError("email", "This email is already registered!");
        fails++;
    }
    if (fails != 0) {
        return INPUT;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

My redirect inside struts.xml:

```
<action name="validate_member" class="managementAction" method="validateMemberForm">
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">create_member</param>
            <param name="company">${company}</param>
            <param name="upload">${upload}</param> <!-- THIS PARAM IS OF TYPE FILE -->
            <param name="uploadContentType">${uploadContentType}</param>
            <param name="uploadFileName">${uploadFileName}</param>
            <param name="email">${email}</param>
        </result>
        <result name="input">/pages/authenticated/memberSave.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

And my 'create_member' action returns INPUT.

Comment: Not to be overtly picky but why not just use: public void validate() method to contain your field error code? See: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/form-validation.html then you don't need the redirect and the action dedicated to validation only.

Comment: HTTP params are strings. You can't redirect with a file in any meaningful way.

Comment: Thanks. @Quaternion I want my class to contain more than one actions, that's why I do not use void validate().

Comment: You can use the validateXxx() form to include multiple validation methods into one class...  Dave pointed out the redirect limitation but if you insist on this separation you could chain...

Comment: Cheers @Quaternion. Didn't know about this approach, this has solved my problem.

Comment: @Bravo related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27114916/1654265